# Linux on Apple M1 (Mac Mini)

Tags: linux, kernel

I'm trying to install Linux on a Mac M1 processor.

I use the tutorial at https://corellium.com/blog/linux-m1 (I have tried the USB option). When I boot the system, I get the following error message:

```
invalid mach-O boot properties
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a very early version, use the [alpha release of Asahi Linux](https://asahilinux.org/2022/03/asahi-linux-alpha-release/).

1. Update macOS to the newest version.
2. Log in as an administrator.
3. Run `curl https://alx.sh | sh`.
4. Follow the directions.